# Clean field value handling inside views_handler_field subclass?

Tags: entities, views

I am writing a few views_handler_field subclasses that render fields of my entity depending on other values of the entity. The examples I see use a very awkward way of accessing the other field data, eg.

```
function render($values) {
  if (isset($values->field_name[0])) {
    $my_stuff = $values->field_name[0]['raw']['value'];
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there a clean way of accessing other fields in the entity, like EntityMetadataWrapper? I would just load the entity and create a EMW instance but that seems expensive to do for each cell in a big table.

Answer (score 0):

[field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and [field_view_value()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) are as clean as it gets without Entity API.